# iOS 7 mobile Safari no longer supports <input type="datetime"/>

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari

I have a rather large **iPad** application built using PhoneGap and I was doing some testing to make sure everything was going to work appropriately in **iOS** 7.  The most significant issue I have found is that `<input type="datetime"/>` is no longer supported.

I have seen several posted suggesting you need to now have two separate fields for date and time. This is a really huge change because I am using this all over the application. I am hoping this is just something broken in the beta release of **iOS** 7 since it is an **HTML** 5 standard input type but I can't seem to find any information.

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: based on this http://iosdeveloperforums.com/f6/ios-7-safari-dont-support-date-time-input-433.html it is no longer supported. I'm also dealing with this problem and the only option I can think so far is to separate the fields though it would be a huge change.

Comment: Hi, what about <input type=\"date\" and <input type="time"? Does ios7 support them? thx

Answer (score 16):

Support for `datetime` has been removed, but you can use `datetime-local` instead. From what I hear (can't say from whom) it's here to stay.

Comment: Any links, for reference?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this input type was removed in iOS 7

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

> Following Google Chrome, now Safari on iOS doesn’t support the
>   datetime input type anymore and it will fallback to text. This type
>   was deprecated in the standard in favor of using two inputs, date and
>   time for the same purpose. The problem is that datetime was compatible
>   with iOS from version 5.0 to 6.1; if you are using it, be careful!

Comment: I looked for evidence of this or a blog post backing it up, but came up empty: There's still a spec for `input[type="datetime"]` on the W3C site. Do you know where the change was documented?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the datetime-local but you have to make sure you take into account the timezone when binding to and from the control.  We want to store GMT time in the database.  I used the below functions to convert back and forth during binding.

```
function formatHTML5DateTime(date)
{
try
{
    if (typeof(date) == 'undefined' || date == null || date == '') return "";

    var tmpDate = new Date(date);
    // gets the timezone offset in minutes
    var offset = tmpDate.getTimezoneOffset();
    // apply the timezone offset in reverse to local time
    var newDate = tmpDate.addMinutes(Math.abs(offset) * -1);

    return newDate.toISOString().replace("Z", "");
}
catch(e)
{
    return "";
}
}

function formatJSDate(date)
{
try
{
    if (typeof(date) == 'undefined' || date == null || date == '') return "";

    var tmpDate = new Date(date);
    // gets the timezone offset in minutes
    var offset = tmpDate.getTimezoneOffset();
    // apply the timezone offset to UTC time
    var newDate = tmpDate.addMinutes(offset);

    return newDate.toISOString();
}
catch(e)
{
    return "";
}
}
```

Answer (score -4):

See the reference [here](http://demo.hongkiat.com/html5-form-input-type/index1.html)

Your CSS should be change as below:

```
{ 
align-items: center;
display: -webkit-inline-flex; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding: 0px; 
-webkit-padding-start: 1px; 
}
```