# expand input date calendar (browser native)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

Is it possible to expand a native browser calendar..

```
<input id="calendar" type="date"></input>
```

..just like you're actually clicking on it?

I tried simulating a click event:

```
$('#calendar').trigger('click');
```

but no luck. Ideas? [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f10tnurq/)

PS: i'm **not** interested in plugins like jquery datepicker etc. Thanks

Comment: Since they're not universally supported anyway, I think you're better off just creating your own inline calendar.

Comment: actually i don't need to be universally supported, but thanks anyway

Comment: Hardly supported at all is more like it. No support in IE or FF

Comment: i know, but it is supported for the cases i need: Android > 4.3 and iOS > 7.1. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: iOS (and AFAIK mobile Chrome) doesn't use a calendar for the [`type=datetime-local`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445927/ios-7-mobile-safari-no-longer-supports-input-type-datetime) picker anyway -- it's a set of spinners that appears in place of a keyboard -- so you wouldn't get what you're asking for anyway. What are you really wanting here?

Comment: yes ofc, every browser will use his own native calendar/datepicker/spinner or whatever it is. that's what i'm trying to achieve. i just want to know if it's possible to trigger it with some event

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to trigger any event to display Native DatePicker/TimePicker.
If browser supports HTML5 input type date/time, then it will open native DatePicker/TimePicker.
Check this [example](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this hack -

[http://jsfiddle.net/f4tmz4td/](http://jsfiddle.net/4augjtjn/)

HTML

```
<input id="calendar" type="date"></input>
<input class="button" type="button" value="Click"/>
```

CSS

```
#calendar {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 15px;
}

.button{
  float: right;
}
```

Uses CSS to position the datepicker just over the btn. The datepicker is hidden using Opacity: 0 so users can see your button.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but what i meant was to programmatically simulate that click event to open the calendar