# Meteor Autoform - Submitting Hidden Input Works on Desktop but not mobile

Tags: html, forms, meteor, meteor-autoform

**my question is:** Does anyone know why hidden form inputs would be submitted on a desktop browser but not on mobile?  On desktop I have tested with FireFox and Safari.  On mobile, I have tested with Safari.

**background**

I have a an autoForm that uses a custom widget to allow the user to select the date and time for an event.

In this widget, there are three input fields: date, time, and timezone (in case the event is in a different timezone).

There are two hidden input fields, one for the datetime object, and one for the timezone that the user selected (stored separately so I know how to display it back to them later).

When I submit this form on my laptop, everything works as expected.  The three visible values are discarded and the the two hidden inputs get written to the database.

However, when testing on a mobile browser (iPhone 6/Safari), the hidden inputs are apparently not being captured and I can't submit the form because the date is a required key.

Not sure if this will help, but fwiw my autoform looks like this:

```
   {{#autoForm collection="Events" id="updateEndDate" type="update" doc=this resetOnSuccess="false"}}
     <fieldset>
     {{> afFieldInput name="endDate" type="dateAndTime" }}
   </fieldset>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
       <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
     </button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancelForm" type="cancel">
       <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
     </button>
   {{/autoForm}}
```

And my custom "dateAndTime" widget looks like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control hidden"
    data-schema-key={{this.name}}
    name={{this.name}}
    type="datetime-local" value={{dateTime}}>

    <div class="form-inline">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control"
        id="date" placeholder="Select a date"
        type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control typeahead"
        data-autoselect=true data-highlight="true"
        data-selected="timeSelected"
        data-source="times" id="time"
        placeholder="Add a time?"
        spellcheck="off" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            {{> timezonePicker class="form-control" selected=timezoneName }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control hidden" type="text"
     name={{this.atts.tzName}} data-schema-key={{this.atts.tzName}} value= {{selectedTimezone}}>
    <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name=this.atts.tzName}}</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445927/ios-7-mobile-safari-no-longer-supports-input-type-datetime) it looks like the `datetime` input type is not supported in iOS Safari. I would think that's why you're having this problem, and will need to separate the `datetime` field into 2 separate fields - one for `date`, and another for `time`.

[Here's a bit more info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) on this subject, and you can compare all the differences between something like chrome and iOS safari [here](http://caniuse.com/#compare=chrome+43,ios_saf+8.1-8.3).

Comment: thanks.  never would have thought that was the issue ... so you just saved me a ton of head scratching.  i just changed my input type to text on my hidden input, and everything works fine.